# Returning object item from an array

Tags: php, laravel

I need to loop through an array and return a property of the object of that item.

My array has this format:

[image: Arquivo mongodb array de links]

I tried to solve this with the following function:

```
public function returnObjectByDayAndTrip ($ links, $ trip, $ dayOperation)
    {
        $ newArray = array_filter ($ links, function ($ obj) use ($ trip, $ dayOperation) {
            if ($ obj ['trip'] == $ trip && $ obj ['dayOperation'] === $ dayOperation) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (isset ($ newArray [0])) {
            return $ newArray [0] ['url'];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And to call her use:

```
$link-> week = $ this-> returnObjectByDayAndTrip ($ links, $ trip, 'week');
```

Where `$links` is my array of the image, `$trip` is the day I need to get, and 'week' is the day of operation I need to get.

My error happens when for example the item is the [3] of the array, when it is the first everything works more from position [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5KOq.png) nothing works anymore.

My return with `var_dump` is

> object(stdClass)#632 (4) { ["week"]=> string(77) "/horario-de-onibus-010-bela-vista-santa-ruth-destino-santa-ruth-em-dias-uteis" ["saturday"]=> NULL ["sunday"]=> NULL ["changeDestiny"]=> NULL }

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["_id"]=> object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId)#477 (1) { ["oid"]=> string(24) "5b3f74ad6ae83d00223504e8" } ["url"]=> string(77) "/horario-de-onibus-010-bela-vista-santa-ruth-destino-santa-ruth-em-dias-uteis" ["dayOperation"]=> string(4) "week" ["trip"]=> string(5) "tripA" } } 

array(1) { [2]=> array(4) { ["_id"]=> object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId)#479 (1) { ["oid"]=> string(24) "5b3f74ad6ae83d00223504e6" } ["url"]=> string(73) "/horario-de-onibus-010-bela-vista-santa-ruth-destino-santa-ruth-no-sabado" ["dayOperation"]=> string(8) "saturday" ["trip"]=> string(5) "tripA" } } 

array(1) { [4]=> array(4) { ["_id"]=> object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId)#481 (1) { ["oid"]=> string(24) "5b3f74ad6ae83d00223504e4" } ["url"]=> string(74) "/horario-de-onibus-010-bela-vista-santa-ruth-destino-santa-ruth-no-domingo" ["dayOperation"]=> string(6) "sunday" ["trip"]=> string(5) "tripA" } } 

array(1) { [1]=> array(4) { ["_id"]=> object(MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId)#478 (1) { ["oid"]=> string(24) "5b3f74ad6ae83d00223504e7" } ["url"]=> string(77) "/horario-de-onibus-010-bela-vista-santa-ruth-destino-bela-vista-em-dias-uteis" ["dayOperation"]=> string(4) "week" ["trip"]=> string(5) "tripB" } }
```

I need to return the url of the object based on the particularity passed to function. In my array will necessarily have only 1 items or none that satisfies the information reported, ie always have a result or none.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve using `current ()` it returns the first position of an array so it looks like this:

```
public function returnObjectByDayAndTrip ($ links, $ trip, $ dayOperation)
{
    $ newArray = array_filter ($ links, function ($ obj) use ($ trip, $ dayOperation) {
        if ($ obj ['trip'] == $ trip && $ obj ['dayOperation'] === $ dayOperation) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });


    if (count ($ newArray)> = 1) {
        return current ($ newArray) ['url'];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

There is probably a better way to do it, and I even accept this new methods but this way it solved my problem. The ideal here is a join with `array_map` and`array_filter` to get robust.